# Consulta Eloquent ORM

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, orm

Preciso gerar uma consulta no eloquent ORM que no phpmyadmin está funcionando. A consulta em si pega, de cada registro agrupado, a data mais recente. O campo para agrupamento seria 'onibus_ponto' (de vários registros de campo 'onibus_ponto' pega a data mais recente). Segue:

```
select 
    a.onibus_ponto, a.data, a.restart
from 
    pontos as a
inner JOIN (
    select 
        onibus_ponto, max(data) as data 
    from 
        pontos 
    group by 
        onibus_ponto
        ) 
as b
where 
    restart >= 10 
group by 
    onibus_ponto
```

Agradecido!

Answer (score 0):

Se você quiser usar o query builder do laravel, provavelmente ficaria algo assim:

```
$subQuery = DB::table("pontos")->select("onibus_ponto")->max("data")->groupBy("onibus_ponto");
    
$query = DB::table("pontos")
 ->joinSub($subQuery,"subquery_table", function ($join) {
   $join->on("pontos.onibus_ponto", "=", "subquery_table.onibus_ponto")
 })
 ->select("pontos.onibus_ponto", "pontos.data", "pontos.restart")
 ->where("restart", ">=", "10")
 ->groupBy("onibus_ponto");
```

Só lembrar de importar classe no seu código com: **use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;**